# Multiple sources for a javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a project where I need to include somewhat around 10-15 .js files in the HTML head section directly like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:9020/website1/wa/min/soundmanager2.js,vars.js,utils/md5.js,utils/utils.js></script>
```

what is the way I can give refrences correctly

the files I need to refre are in the same hierarchy like

1.....2,3
2.........4,5
3........6,7

I need to refer 1,4,7 please **help**.

somewhere I read this method what's it?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:9020/wordplus/root/child/?b=scripts&f=soundmanager2.js,vars.js,utils/md5.js,utils/utils.js></script>
```

Comment: It is not at all clear what you're asking for. A single `<script>` tag can import **one** script from **one** URL.

Comment: you cannot CSV list files to load, each `script` must have a src to a single file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you posted looks exactly like the query string interface for the minify PHP library: http://github.com/mrclay/minify

Using it you use it in the fashion `<script src="min/?b=path&f=script1.js,script2.js,ui/script3.js"></script>`.
Where `path` is the path from your web root that you want it to look for scripts under.

I've used it before and I've found it quite effective. It concatenates, minifies, caches, and serves JS and CSS.

I'm sure there are other libraries to achieve the same effect, alternatively you can create a build script to concatenate and minify all your scripts and then deploy a single JS file to your site, in a single script tag.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to load multiple javascript files in a single `<script>` element.

You have to have to have an individual `<script>` element for each script you are referencing..

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://localhost:9020/wordplus/root/child/?b=scripts&f=soundmanager2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://localhost:9020/wordplus/root/child/?b=scripts&f=vars.js"></script>
```

Comment: what do we mean by "b" and "f" in /?b=scripts&f=soundmanager2.js

Comment: you had ?b and &f in your original post,

Comment: No I said there I read it somewhere. 
what are they for?
Please dont make me ask things again

Comment: Apologies, @user1491704, I was away from the computer. I didn't realise what you were asking... but if you take that attitude with the people who are doing things in their own time to help you, you will find you will quickly lose reputation. As others have said it looks like its using serverside scripting, and as others have said its better to have individual script elements.

Comment: @freefaller
my apologies too for being rude

Comment: Not a problem, @user1491704, hope you get your project working :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll get what you need from dynamically loading external javascript files:

http://ntt.cc/2008/02/10/4-ways-to-dynamically-load-external-javascriptwith-source.html

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml

Answer (score 0):

The second line you posted requests scripts from the server dynamically.  the `b` parameter of the request tells it you want scripts and the `f` parameter tells the server which files you want.  Then it concatenates these into one file and sends that back to the user agent.  You need server-side scripting to handle this; it is not something built into the URL specification.

```
http://localhost:9020/wordplus/root/child/
b=scripts
f=soundmanager2.js,vars.js,utils/md5.js,utils/utils.js
```

The simplest solution is just have one script tag per file as it will let you take advantage of caching:

```
<script src="http://localhost:9020/wordplus/root/child/soundmanager2.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:9020/wordplus/root/child/vars.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:9020/wordplus/root/child/utils/md5.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:9020/wordplus/root/child/utils/utils.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use some JavaScript builder to join all your files, generating just one. The pros of this approach is that your result file will be "compressed" (minified). Some builders:

- [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) (I like and use this since 2009).
- [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)